# How can I run this Gazebo simulation? The launch file is not seen as a launch file

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firstly I'm really really new to ROS. I need to import this world and get it open in Gazebo for a simulation: (https://github.com/aws-robotics/aws-robomaker-hospital-world)

but when its time to launch I get the error that the launch file is not a launch file. So I wondered if I did the wrong steps before I can launch. I'm using ROS development studio for the terminal and Gazebo. So I tried with another project my co-worker sent me and it worked, here are the steps I took:

1. git clone the project into simulation_ws src
2. then go back to simulation_ws and enter "catkin_make"
3. then I enter "source devel/setup.bash"
4. then i enter roslaunch "file name" "launch file name"
5. Open Gazebo window where robot shows up

but this doesn't work with the project in the link above, so I must be missing something in the steps I took since I'm such a newbie. On the readme it says to include some code in the launch file but when you check one of them the line is already there so I've no idea what that means.

What do you all think?

*edit
here is my input commands:

```
cd simulation_ws

cd src

git clone https://github.com/aws-robotics/aws-robomaker-hospital-world.git

cd ..

catkin_make

source devel.setup.bash

roslaunch aws-robomaker-hospital-world hospital.launch
```

the terminal output is:

```
RLException: [hospital.launch] is neither a launch file in package [aws-robomaker-hospital-world] nor is [aws-robomaker-hospital-world] a launch file name The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367904/how-can-i-run-this-gazebo-simulation?-the-launch-file-is-not-seen-as-a-launch-file/) by [ROSNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/65770/rosnewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-12-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-12-17**:
Can you post the exact commands and error?  Please, use the `101010` button to format code and terminal input/output.

**Comment by [ROSNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/65770/rosnewbie/) on 2020-12-17**:
Hello tryan, I edited the post with the details you requested. Hope this helps. thanks.

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2020-12-17**:
I'm assuming `devel.setup.bash` was a typo and in reality you ran `source devel/setup.bash`, right?

**Comment by [ROSNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/65770/rosnewbie/) on 2020-12-17**:
you're right chifritz, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The name of that package is different from its folder name, as can be seen using rospack:

```
> rospack list | grep aws
aws_robomaker_hospital_world /home/cfritz/work/lumin/software/catkin/src/aws-robomaker-hospital-world
```

So you need to run:

```
source devel/setup.bash
roslaunch aws_robomaker_hospital_world hospital.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-12-17**:
@ROSNewbie, note the underscores in place of the dashes in the package name.  While some places (GitHub, `apt` repositories, etc.) use the dash convention, ROS package names follow the underscore convention.  As cfritz pointed out, the ROS package name isn't always the same as its folder's name, but you can find it in its `package.xml` file when in doubt.

**Comment by [ROSNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/65770/rosnewbie/) on 2020-12-17**:
@chfritz  thanks for the answer it solved the issue.

**Comment by [ROSNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/65770/rosnewbie/) on 2020-12-17**:
@tyan thanks for the help.